# How to get adb access to recovery mode

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, zip

My phone is stuck in boot loop, but I rooted it before. I want to get adb access to push some files which I deleted causing the loop. 
I tried Power + Volume up. But I can't grant adb access there. I use Gionee P5 mini.
What can I do?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Boot to recovery or gain ADB access?

Comment: You could try to flash the entire device with original firmware if it's online anywhere, Needrom.com is a good place to start.

Comment: I deleted some system files, now the OS won't boot. I can't find any ROM for the device. So I want to get adb access to push back those files.